# AWS Textract detecting lines not blocks

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ocr, amazon-textract

I am currently using `Amplify Framework` for Android and its prediction plugin, which is basically `AWS Textract`, to convert images to text.

Previously, I was using `Firebase` text recognition feature which was dividing the text into blocks and into lines and words inside each one.
Textract, on the other hand, divides text only into lines.

[image: Lines in AWS Textract vs blocks in Firebase OCR]

Images that I use are often screenshots and they often contain more than just one column of text. Because now I get only lines, I don't know how to divide my text into blocks.

Is there a way to configure the `Textract` to divide text first into blocks? Or is there a way to divide it accurately manually?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Textract doesn't provide a blocking of sections/paragraphs feature.

Textract text detection returns 3 main objects: Pages, Line Blocks, and Word Blocks [[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/how-it-works-lines-words.html)].

Included in JSON response object for Line/Word blocks is a Geometry object which defines a Bounding Box and Polygon [[2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/text-location.html)].  In order to achieve your desired results, with Textract response data, you would have to further process the Line Blocks based on their Geometry data group them as you see fit.